# Rolling Sum by Another Variable in R

Tags: r, data.table, xts

I want to get the rolling 7-day sum by ID.  Suppose my data looks like this:

```
data<-as.data.frame(matrix(NA,42,3))
data$V1<-seq(as.Date("2014-05-01"),as.Date("2014-09-01"),by=3)
data$V2<-rep(1:6,7)
data$V3<-rep(c(1,2),21)
colnames(data)<-c("Date","USD","ID")

         Date USD ID
1  2014-05-01   1  1
2  2014-05-04   2  2
3  2014-05-07   3  1
4  2014-05-10   4  2
5  2014-05-13   5  1
6  2014-05-16   6  2
7  2014-05-19   1  1
8  2014-05-22   2  2
9  2014-05-25   3  1
10 2014-05-28   4  2
```

How can I add a new column that will contain the rolling 7-day sum by ID?

Comment: This might get you started: `library(xts); lapply(split(data, data$ID), function(x) apply.weekly(xts(x[, 2:3], x$Date), sum))`

Comment: @jbaums `apply.weekly` (which is a wrapper for `period.apply`) applies a function to non-overlapping periods, which is different than a rolling period.

Answer (score 8):

If your data is big, you might want to check out this solution which uses `data.table`.  It is pretty fast.  If you need more speed, you can always change `mapply` to `mcmapply` and use multiple cores.

```
#Load data.table and convert to data.table object
require(data.table)
setDT(data)[,ID2:=.GRP,by=c("ID")]

#Build reference table
Ref <- data[,list(Compare_Value=list(I(USD)),Compare_Date=list(I(Date))), by=c("ID2")]

#Use mapply to get last seven days of value by id
data[,Roll.Val := mapply(RD = Date,NUM=ID2, function(RD, NUM) {
                  d <- as.numeric(Ref$Compare_Date[[NUM]] - RD)
                  sum((d <= 0 & d >= -7)*Ref$Compare_Value[[NUM]])})]
```

Comment: @Mike.Gahan Well that works but I do not posses what it takes to understand it. I would like to see what the code would be if you removed the complexity of the ID. How would you do it if you simply wanted a rolling 7 day sum or a rolling 9 day sum?

Comment: If the ID is the same for each observation, then it works as you want it to. So the solution generalizes to your problem. I would imagine rollapply works pretty well for a simplified version of this problem as well.

Comment: @Mike.Gahan I have seen rollapply where people just take the last 7 rows but yours is different since you are actually calculating what the range is since there may not be a row for each day. Where I get lost (because I am not really a programer) is the way you calculate the index positions corresponding to each range's span. Can you please write the code where the complexity of of ID is left out? I may be able to follow that...I hope.

Comment: It's much faster if you have `d <- as.integer(Ref$Compare_Date[[NUM]]) - as.integer(RD)`

Answer (score 7):

Dataset provided by OP does not expose the complexity of the task. In terms of addressing OP question so far only Mike's answer was the correct one.
In fact for a 8 rolling days, instead of 7 rolling days, due to `d <= 0 & d >= -7`.
`zoo` solution by @G. Grothendieck is almost valid, only if `merge` would be made to each group of `ID`.
Below second data.table solution, this time valid results, using dev RcppRoll which allows `na.rm=TRUE`.
And slightly formatted Mike's solution output.

```r
data<-as.data.frame(matrix(NA,42,3))
data$V1<-seq(as.Date("2014-05-01"),as.Date("2014-09-01"),by=3)
data$V2<-rep(1:6,7)
data$V3<-rep(c(1,2),21)
colnames(data)<-c("Date","USD","ID")

library(microbenchmark)
library(RcppRoll) # install_github("kevinushey/RcppRoll")
library(data.table) # install_github("Rdatatable/data.table")
correct_jan_dt = function(n, partial=TRUE){
  DT = as.data.table(data) # this can be speedup by setDT()
  date.range = DT[,range(Date)]
  all.dates = seq.Date(date.range[1],date.range[2],by=1)
  setkey(DT,ID,Date)
  r = DT[CJ(unique(ID),all.dates)][, c("roll") := as.integer(roll_sumr(USD, n, normalize = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)), by="ID"][!is.na(USD)]
  # This could be simplified when `partial` arg will be implemented in [kevinushey/RcppRoll](https://github.com/kevinushey/RcppRoll)
  if(isTRUE(partial)){
    r[is.na(roll), roll := cumsum(USD), by="ID"][]
  }
  return(r[order(Date,ID)])
}
correct_mike_dt = function(){
  data = as.data.table(data)[,ID2:=.GRP,by=c("ID")]
  #Build reference table
  Ref <- data[,list(Compare_Value=list(I(USD)),Compare_Date=list(I(Date))), by=c("ID2")]
  #Use mapply to get last seven days of value by id
  data[, c("roll") := mapply(RD = Date,NUM=ID2, function(RD, NUM){
    d <- as.numeric(Ref$Compare_Date[[NUM]] - RD)
    sum((d <= 0 & d >= -7)*Ref$Compare_Value[[NUM]])})][,ID2:=NULL][]
}
identical(correct_mike_dt(), correct_jan_dt(n=8,partial=TRUE))
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(unit="relative", times=5L, correct_mike_dt(), correct_jan_dt(8))
# Unit: relative
#               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  correct_mike_dt() 274.0699 273.9892 267.2886 266.6009 266.2254 256.7296     5
#  correct_jan_dt(8)   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000     5
```

Looking forward for update from @Khashaa.

### Edit (20150122.2): Below benchmarks do not answer OP question.

Timing on a bigger (still very tiny) dataset, 5439 rows:

```r
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)
library(microbenchmark)
data<-as.data.frame(matrix(NA,5439,3))
data$V1<-seq(as.Date("1970-01-01"),as.Date("2014-09-01"),by=3)
data$V2<-sample(1:6,5439,TRUE)
data$V3<-sample(c(1,2),5439,TRUE)
colnames(data)<-c("Date","USD","ID")
zoo_f = function(){
    z <- read.zoo(data)
    z0 <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "day")), fill = 0) # expand to daily
    roll <- function(x) rollsumr(x, 7, fill = NA)
    transform(data, roll = ave(z0$USD, z0$ID, FUN = roll)[time(z)])
}
dt_f = function(){
    DT = as.data.table(data) # this can be speedup by setDT()
    date.range = DT[,range(Date)]
    all.dates = seq.Date(date.range[1],date.range[2],by=1)
    setkey(DT,Date)
    DT[.(all.dates)
       ][order(Date), c("roll") := rowSums(setDT(shift(USD, 0:6, NA, "lag")),na.rm=FALSE), by="ID"
         ][!is.na(ID)]
}
dp_f = function(){
  data %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(roll=roll_sum(c(rep(NA,6), USD), 7))
} 
dt2_f = function(){
  # this can be speedup by setDT()
  as.data.table(data)[, c("roll") := roll_sum(c(rep(NA,6), USD), 7), by="ID"][]
}
identical(as.data.table(zoo_f()),dt_f())
# [1] TRUE
identical(setDT(as.data.frame(dp_f())),dt_f())
# [1] TRUE
identical(dt2_f(),dt_f())
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(unit="relative", times=20L, zoo_f(), dt_f(), dp_f(), dt2_f())
# Unit: relative
#     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  zoo_f() 140.331889 141.891917 138.064126 139.381336 136.029019 137.730171    20
#   dt_f()  14.917166  14.464199  15.210757  16.898931  16.543811  14.221987    20
#   dp_f()   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000    20
#  dt2_f()   1.536896   1.521983   1.500392   1.518641   1.629916   1.337903    20
```

Yet I'm not sure if my data.table code is already optimal.

Above functions did not answer OP question. Read the top of post for update. Mike's solution was the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Assuming you mean every successive overlapping 7 rows for that ID:

```
library(zoo)

transform(data, roll = ave(USD, ID, FUN = function(x) rollsumr(x, 7, fill = NA)))
```

**2)** If you really did mean 7 days and not 7 rows then try this:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(data)
z0 <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "day")), fill = 0) # expand to daily
roll <- function(x) rollsumr(x, 7, fill = NA)
transform(data, roll = ave(z0$USD, z0$ID, FUN = roll)[time(z)])
```

**Updated** Added (2) and made some improvements.

Comment: This is a nice, simple, and (i find) quite fast solution

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(Date = seq(as.Date("2014-05-01"),
                              as.Date("2014-09-01"),
                              by = 3),
                   USD = rep(1:6, 7),
                   ID = rep(c(1, 2), 21))

data[, Rolling7DaySum := {
         d <- data$Date - Date
         sum(data$USD[ID == data$ID & d <= 0 & d >= -7])
       },
     by = list(Date, ID)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is some problem with Mike.Gahan's suggested code and correct it as below after testing it out.

```
require(data.table)
setDT(data)[,ID2:=.GRP,by=c("ID")]
Ref <-data[,list(Compare_Value=list(I(USD)),Compare_Date=list(I(Date))),by=c("ID2")]
data[,Roll.Val := mapply(RD = Date,NUM=ID2, function(RD, NUM) {
d <- as.numeric(Ref[ID2 == NUM,]$Compare_Date[[1]] - RD)
sum((d <= 0 & d >= -7)*Ref[ID2 == NUM,]$Compare_Value[[1]])})]
```