# Fastest way for doing 21 day rolling sum for an ActivityType

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, zoo

I have a large dataframe(3M+ rows). I am trying to count the number of times a certain ActivityType appears in a 21 day window. I have modelled my solution from [Rolling Sum by Another Variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397299/rolling-sum-by-another-variable-in-r/24400600#24400600). But it takes a long time just for one ActivityType. I did not think 3M+ rows is something that will take an inordinate amount of time. Below is what I tried:

```
dt <- read.table(text='

                         Name      ActivityType     ActivityDate                
                         John       Email            1/1/2014           
                         John       Email            1/3/2014                
                         John       Webinar          1/5/2014          
                         John       Webinar          1/20/2014          
                         John       Webinar          3/25/2014          
                         John       Email            4/1/2014           
                         John       Email            4/20/2014          
                         Tom        Email            1/1/2014           
                         Tom       Webinar           1/5/2014           
                         Tom       Webinar           1/20/2014          
                         Tom       Webinar           3/25/2014          
                         Tom       Email             4/1/2014           
                         Tom       Email             4/20/2014          

                         ', header=T, row.names = NULL)

        library(data.table)
        library(reshape2)
        dt$ActivityType <- factor(dt$ActivityType)   
        dt$ActivityDate <- as.Date(dt$ActivityDate, "%m/%d/%Y")  
        dt <- dt[order(dt$Name, dt$ActivityDate),]

   dt <- dcast(dt, Name + ActivityDate ~ ActivityType, fun.aggregate=length)
   setDT(dt)
   #Build reference table
        Ref <- dt[,list(Compare_Value=list(I(Email)),Compare_Date=list(I(ActivityDate))), by=c("Name")]
    #Use mapply to get last 21 days of value by Name    
    dt[,Email_RollingSum := mapply(ActivityDate=ActivityDate,Name=Name, function(ActivityDate, Name) {
            d <- as.numeric(Ref$Compare_Date[[Name]] - ActivityDate)
            sum((d <= 0 & d >= -21)*Ref$Compare_Value[[Name]])})]
```

And this is just for ActivityType=Email, then I have to do the same for other ActivityType levels. The link that I got the solution from talked about using "mcapply" rather than "mapply". Kindly let me know how I can use mcapply or any other solution that will make it faster.

Below is the expected output. For each row, I take the ActivityDate and 21 days before that and that 21 day period is my time window. I count all the time ActivityType="Email" appears in that time window.

```
              Name      ActivityType     ActivityDate  Email_RollingSum             
                 John       Email            1/1/2014         1  
                 John       Email            1/3/2014         2       
                 John       Webinar          1/5/2014         2 
                 John       Webinar          1/20/2014        2  
                 John       Webinar          3/25/2014        0  
                 John       Email            4/1/2014         1  
                 John       Email            4/20/2014        2 
                 Tom        Email            1/1/2014         1  
                 Tom       Webinar           1/5/2014         1  
                 Tom       Webinar           1/20/2014        1  
                 Tom       Webinar           3/25/2014        0  
                 Tom       Email             4/1/2014         1  
                 Tom       Email             4/20/2014        2
```

Comment: I often convert my dates to numeric when dealing with millions of rows. as.numeric(dt$ActivityDate). Not a solution but perhaps an improvement.

Comment: Since the OP is explicitly about speed it would be good to update it with the timings you got with the various methods.

Comment: The approach by WaltS took 1.89 hours. For some reason, I ran out of memory twice while trying eddi's approach. Khasana's approach was running(a little more than 2 hours) when excel crashed my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try an approach in which the data table is used both for list of names and dates and for the source of number of emails.  This is done in `data.table` by using the `DT` in the `i` argument of `DT` together with `by = .EACHI`.  Code could look like:

```
library(data.table)
# convert character dates to Date types
dt$ActivityDate <- as.Date(dt$ActivityDate, "%m/%d/%Y") 
# convert to a 'data.table' and define key
setDT(dt, key = "Name")
# count emails and webinars
dt <- dt[dt[,.(Name, type = ActivityType, date = ActivityDate)],
         .(type, date,
           Email = sum(ActivityType == "Email" & between(ActivityDate, date-21, date)),
           Webinar = sum(ActivityType == "Webinar" & between(ActivityDate, date-21, date))),
         by=.EACHI]
```

The following uses the same approach as above but includes a few changes which may improve the speed by 30-40% depending upon your data.

```
  setDT(dt, key = "Name")
  dt[, ":="(ActivityDate = as.Date(dt$ActivityDate, "%m/%d/%Y"),
            ActivityType = as.character(ActivityType) )]
  dt4 <- dt[.(Name=Name,  type=ActivityType, date=ActivityDate), {z=between(ActivityDate, date-21, date);
                                                                  .( type, date,  
                                                                     Email=sum( (ActivityType %chin% "Email") & z),
                                                                     Webinar=sum( (ActivityType %chin% "Webinar") & z) ) }
            , by=.EACHI]
```

Comment: `<-` against data.table column is a bad practice

Comment: @gibbz00 the `:=` operator, read [Reference semantics vignette](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html).

Answer (score 6):

```
setDT(dt)
dt[, ActivityDate := as.Date(ActivityDate, '%m/%d/%Y')]

# add index to keep track of rows
dt[, idx := .I]

# match the dates we're looking for using a rolling join and extract the row numbers
rr = dt[.(Name = Name, ActivityDate = ActivityDate - 21, refIdx = idx),
       .(idx, refIdx), on = c('Name', 'ActivityDate'), roll = -Inf]
#    idx refIdx
# 1:   1      1
# 2:   1      2
# 3:   1      3
# 4:   1      4
# 5:   5      5
# 6:   5      6
# 7:   6      7
# 8:   8      8
# 9:   8      9
#10:   8     10
#11:  11     11
#12:  11     12
#13:  12     13

# extract the above rows and count occurrences using dcast
dcast(rr[, {seq = idx:refIdx; dt[seq]}, by = 1:nrow(rr)], nrow ~ ActivityType)
#   nrow Email Webinar
#1     1     1       0
#2     2     2       0
#3     3     2       1
#4     4     2       2
#5     5     0       1
#6     6     1       1
#7     7     2       0
#8     8     1       0
#9     9     1       1
#10   10     1       2
#11   11     0       1
#12   12     1       1
#13   13     2       0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!